# Mysql query of Facebook style wall

Tags: mysql, sql, facebook, union, facebook-wall

I want to create Members Wall (facebook style) in my website.
Based on:

- Last comments of member's friends.
- Last files of member's friends.
- Last comments of member's files.

Tables structures:

```
friendship
userid | friendid | status
---------------------------------
user_table
userid | username
---------------------------------
files_table
file_id | file_title | file_desc | dl_date
---------------------------------
comments_table
comid | userid | file_id | com_date
```

This is my mysql query and it works. But i want to know your ideas to make it better.

```
--Last files of member's friends
-- Find files of friendship.friendid=$userid
SELECT files_table.file_id AS c1, files_table.file_title AS c2, files_table.file_desc AS c3, files_table.dlauthor AS c4, files_table.dl_date AS date,  IF(files_table.file_id IS NOT NULL, 'Friends_eBooks',FALSE) as Type
    FROM friendship
    LEFT JOIN user_table ON friendship.userid = user_table.userid
    LEFT JOIN files_table ON files_table.dlauthor = user_table.username
    WHERE friendship.friendid = $userid
    AND friendship.STATUS = '1'
-- Find files of friendship.userid=$userid
UNION
SELECT files_table.file_id AS c1, files_table.file_title AS c2, files_table.file_desc AS c3, files_table.dlauthor AS c4, files_table.dl_date AS date,  IF(files_table.file_id IS NOT NULL, 'Friends_eBooks',FALSE) as Type
    FROM friendship
    LEFT JOIN user_table ON friendship.userid = user_table.userid
    LEFT JOIN files_table ON files_table.dlauthor = user_table.username
    WHERE friendship.userid = $userid
    AND friendship.STATUS = '1'
UNION ALL
-- Last comments of member's friends
-- Find comments of friendship.friendid=$userid
SELECT comments_table.comid AS c1, user_table.username AS c2, comments_table.dl_comment AS c3, comments_table.file_id AS c4, comments_table.com_date AS date, IF(comments_table.comid IS NOT NULL, 'Friends_Comments', FALSE) as Type
    FROM friendship
    LEFT JOIN user_table ON friendship.userid = user_table.userid
    LEFT JOIN comments_table ON user_table.userid = comments_table.userid
    WHERE friendship.friendid = $userid
    AND friendship.STATUS = '1'
UNION
-- Find comments of friendship.userid=$userid
SELECT comments_table.comid AS c1, user_table.username AS c2, comments_table.dl_comment AS c3, comments_table.file_id AS c4, comments_table.com_date AS date, IF(comments_table.comid IS NOT NULL, 'Friends_Comments', FALSE) as Type
    FROM friendship
    LEFT JOIN user_table ON friendship.friendid = user_table.userid
    LEFT JOIN comments_table ON user_table.userid = comments_table.userid
    WHERE friendship.userid = $userid
    AND friendship.STATUS = '1'
-- Last comments on member's files
UNION ALL
SELECT comments_table.comid AS c1,user_table.username AS c2,comments_table.dl_comment AS c3, files_table.file_id AS c4,comments_table.com_date AS date, IF(comments_table.comid IS NOT NULL, 'My_Comments', FALSE) as Type
FROM files_table
LEFT JOIN comments_table ON files_table.file_id = comments_table.file_id
LEFT JOIN user_table ON comments_table.userid = user_table.userid
WHERE
(files_table.status=1) AND
(files_table.dlauthor=$userid)
ORDER by date DESC
```

Explain:

```
id  select_type     table   type    possible_keys   key     key_len     ref     rows    Extra
1   PRIMARY     friendship  ref     friendid    friendid    3   const   22  Using where
1   PRIMARY     user_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ketabnak_ebooks.friendship.userid   1    
1   PRIMARY     files_table     ref     dlauthor    dlauthor    92  func    10   
2   UNION   friendship  ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   const   11  Using where
2   UNION   user_table  const   PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   const   1    
2   UNION   files_table     ref     dlauthor    dlauthor    92  func    10   
3   UNION   friendship  ref     friendid    friendid    3   const   22  Using where
3   UNION   user_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ketabnak_ebooks.friendship.userid   1    
3   UNION   comments_table  ref     userid  userid  3   ketabnak_ebooks.user_table.userid   6    
4   UNION   friendship  ref     PRIMARY     PRIMARY     3   const   11  Using where
4   UNION   user_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ketabnak_ebooks.friendship.friendid     1    
4   UNION   comments_table  ref     userid  userid  3   ketabnak_ebooks.user_table.userid   6    
5   UNION   files_table     ref     dlauthor    dlauthor    92  const   294     Using where
5   UNION   comments_table  ref     file_id     file_id     3   ketabnak_ebooks.files_table.file_id     11   
5   UNION   user_table  eq_ref  PRIMARY     PRIMARY     4   ketabnak_ebooks.comments_table.userid   1    
NULL    UNION RESULT    <union1,2,3,4,5>    ALL     NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    Using filesort
```

Weaknesses:

- Query took a lot of time.
- Number of columns of all tables should be equal.

---

I have used `Friendship` table to find all of member's friends.
`Status` is 1 when member's friend has been accepted friendship request.

First, Userid = Memberid:

```
Userid   | Friendid    | Status
1        |      4      |     0
1        |      8      |     1
1        |      9      |     1
```

Then, i have used UNION to merge where Friendid = Memberid:

```
Userid   | Friendid    | Status
2        |      1      |     0
3        |      1      |     0
5        |      1      |     1
```

Comment: Could you please post the execution plan for each query that you union? I suppose that `friendship` table is much less than other and in this case it's will be nice to filter out this table first of all and only than connect it with the rest of the tables in query

Comment: I'm not good at MySQL, as you see.
My query just works but i'm pretty sure that it can be much better.
I do not know how to use `Friendship` table as a filter. May you help?

Comment: To add plan please execute "explain put_your_query_here" and add it to your post. Please try the following query [link](http://pastebin.com/8wbeSwYM) and compare it with your first query in union.

Comment: Explain of my query:
http://pastebin.com/BFz2G1dU
Explain of your query:
http://pastebin.com/4qw89bEZ

Comment: I have used of your idea to rewrite the query:
http://pastebin.com/sMncayxt
It works too. But there is not much different in performance.

Comment: Plans seem to be fine. Could you please make sure that you have index on `friendship.friendid`. That is all i can help you. I guess there is another way to improve (but i could help or cannot.. it depends..): you can rewrite your query and pick out `user_table` from each query in unions and join this table with result set. That is all i can suggest.

Answer (score 3):

One idea to make it better is to stop thinking you have to do everything in a single query.

Answer (score 0):

probably someone has a better idea, of course, there is always someone is smarter than you, anyway I want to share this approach, this was something I did 1 year ago and worked for me, this was done for symfony 1.4, no need to know symfony 1.4, It's self-explanatory .

```
public function getAllEvents($uid) {

    $result = Doctrine_Query::create()->from('AquilaWall w')->where('w.uid = ? && w.is_public=1 ', $uid)->execute();
    $array_uids = array();

    foreach ($result as $uid_record){
        array_push($array_uids, $uid_record->getUid());
        array_push($array_uids, $uid_record->getUids());
    }

    $array_uids = array_unique($array_uids);
    $array_uids = array_filter($array_uids);
    $array_uids = implode(",",$array_uids);

    $mdarray=array();
    $flagg=0;
    $rowcount= $result -> count();

    if ($rowcount>0) {
      // init arrays
      $arr_wall_videos = $arr_wall_comments = $arr_wall_news = $arr_wall_faqs =array();

      $num_videos = $this->getNumberOf("AquilaVideos", $uid);
      if ($num_videos>0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM aquila_videos WHERE uid IN ($array_uids) ";
        $arr_wall_videos = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
        $flagg=1;
      }


      $num_news = $this->getNumberOf("AquilaNews", $uid);
      if ($num_news>0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM aquila_news WHERE uid IN ($array_uids) ";
        $arr_wall_news = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
        $flagg=1;
      }

      $num_faqs = $this->getNumberOf("sfFaqFaq", $uid);
      if ($num_faqs>0) {
        $query = "SELECT  faq.uid, faq.id, faq.created_at, faq.question, faq.slug, cat.name FROM sf_faq_faq faq INNER JOIN sf_faq_category cat on cat.id=faq.category_id WHERE faq.uid IN ($array_uids)";
        $arr_wall_faqs = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
        $flagg=1;
      }

      $num_comments = $this->getNumberOf("Comment", $uid);
      if ($num_comments>0) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM comment WHERE user_id IN ($array_uids) ";
        $arr_wall_comments = Doctrine_Manager::getInstance()->getCurrentConnection()->fetchAssoc($query);
        $flagg=1;
      }

      if ($flagg) {
        $mdarray = array_merge((array)$arr_wall_videos, (array)$arr_wall_faqs);
        $mdarray = array_merge((array)$mdarray, (array)$arr_wall_news);
        $mdarray = array_merge((array)$mdarray, (array)$arr_wall_comments);

        foreach ($mdarray as $key => $row) {
          $dates[$key]  = $row['created_at']; 
        }
        array_multisort($dates, SORT_DESC, $mdarray);
      }
    }

    return $mdarray;

  }
```